# Rails: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

Rails: 5
Ruby: 2.5.3
Gem: gem "ruby_mapscript" 
Error: `/home/usermachine/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3/gems/ruby_mapscript-0.3.0/lib/mapscript/mapscript_extensions.rb:3:in require: libruby-2.0.so.2.0: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory - /home/usermachine/projects/projectname/lib/mapscript.so (LoadError)`

Hi, when I try to start my rails server with "rails s" I get the above error for the ruby_mapscript gem. The file (/home/usermachine/projects/projectname/lib/mapscript.so) is very much present.

I tried `sudo /sbin/ldconfig -v` but the error remains.

Any suggestions?

Comment: How was Ruby initially installed on the machine? It's possible that Ruby needs to be installed with the --enable-shared flag set, which varies slightly depending on how Ruby was installed

Comment: What's the permission on the library file? Probably ok, but make sure you have read access.

Comment: @Tennesseej I installed Ruby using rvm install

Comment: I tried this -> rvm reinstall ruby-2.5.3 --enable-shared and still I have the same problem

Comment: @KavitaC do you see anything labeled as 'not found' when you run this cmd: `ldd /home/usermachine/projects/projectname/lib/mapscript.so`

Comment: I was finally able to resolve this issue buy building mapserver from Git. Thank you all!

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/65000467/12544391 e.g. adding `gem "ffi"` to `Gemfile` fixes it